# WCF MEX Endpoint

Tags: wcf

I am trying to add a MEX endpoint to my service. When I start the service, I'm getting

> WCF Service Host cannot find any service metadata. This may cause the
>   client application to
>   run improperly. Please check if metadata is enabled. Do you want to
>   exit?

Here's my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.CustomerService"
               behaviorConfiguration="Metadata">

        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                  contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Metadata">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Anyone know why I'm still getting the message?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "when I start the service"? How are you hosting the service: self hosting, IIS or using the Visual Studio built in host?

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to specify a mex endpoint AND httpGetEnabled. Only one is required to expose metadata. Do not specifiy httpGetUrl as this is depending on your hosting environment.

try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.CustomerService"
               behaviorConfiguration="Metadata">

        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                  contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

      </service>
    </services>   
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```